# How does this implementation of bitset::count() work?

Tags: c++, c, stl

Here's the implementation of `std::bitset::count` with MSVC 2010:

```
size_t count() const
    {   // count number of set bits
    static char _Bitsperhex[] = "\0\1\1\2\1\2\2\3\1\2\2\3\2\3\3\4";
    size_t _Val = 0;
    for (int _Wpos = _Words; 0 <= _Wpos; --_Wpos)
        for (_Ty _Wordval = _Array[_Wpos]; _Wordval != 0; _Wordval >>= 4)
            _Val += _Bitsperhex[_Wordval & 0xF];
    return (_Val);
    }
```

Can someone explain to me how this is working? what's the trick with `_Bitsperhex`?

Comment: In general, tagging C and C++ is not a good idea unless the question specifically relates to both.  This one looks like it's a C++ question (judging by its use of classes, specifically bitset, which does not exist in C)

Comment: @Wug : I tagged it C because the implementation is coded pretty much in C

Comment: From the asm output, looks like current MSVC uses an 8-bit version of this (256-entry table).  There seems to be no way to tell it that the hardware `popcnt` instruction is available.  (I tried `/Ox /arch:AVX`, which implies SSE4.2 support and thus also popcnt, but the asm output for `std::bitset<32> bs(x); return bs.count()` was still pretty crap: store to the stack and reload it 1 byte at a time, same as with just `/Ox`. https://godbolt.org/g/sGgoSD)  gcc and clang use `popcnt` for `std::bitset::count()`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/109069/224132 for more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_Bitsperhex` contains the number of set bits in a hexadecimal digit, indexed by the digit.

```
digit: 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
value: 0    1    1    2    1    2    2    3    1    2    2    3    2    3    3    4
index: 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    A    B    C    D    E    F
```

The function retrieves one digit at a time from the value it's working with by ANDing with 0xF (binary 1111), looks up the number of set bits in that digit, and sums them.

Comment: ok so basically the inner loop will loop as many times as there are 4 bits in a "word"?

Comment: @lezebulon, the inner loop is actually quite clever - it relies on right shifting to remove 4 bits at a time, and as soon as there are no bits left the loop exits. If the initial value is zero the loop doesn't even run.

Answer (score 4):

`_Bitsperhex` is a 16 element integer array that maps a number in `[0..15]` range to the number of `1` bits in the binary representation of that number. For example, `_Bitsperhex[3]` is equal to `2`, which is the number of `1` bits in the binary representation of `3`.

The rest is easy: each multi-bit word in internal array `_Array` is interpreted as a sequence of 4-bit values. Each 4-bit value is fed through the above `_Bitsperhex` table to count the bits.

It is a slightly different implementation of the lookup table-based method described here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetTable. At the link they use a table of 256 elements and split 32-bit words into four 8-bit values.

Comment: The code shown doesn't have any notion of 8-bit words. It just keeps shifting the native words of the bitset (whatever those are, most probably 32/64-bit uints) by 4. So your description doesn't really explain what this code actually does, even if generally correct.